# Querying a list object from API and returning it into dataframe - issues with format

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, append

I have the below script that returns data in a list format per quote of (i). I set up an empty list, and then query with the API function get_kline_data, and pass each output into my klines_list with the .extend function

```py
klines_list = []
a = ["REQ-ETH","REQ-BTC","XLM-BTC"]
for i in a:
    klines = client.get_kline_data(i, '5min', 1619317366, 1619317606)
    klines_list.extend([i,klines])
klines_list
```

klines_list then returns data in this format;

```py
['REQ-ETH',
 [['1619317500',
   '0.0000491',
   '0.0000491',
   '0.0000491',
   '0.0000491',
   '5.1147',
   '0.00025113177']],
 'REQ-BTC',
 [['1619317500',
   '0.00000219',
   '0.00000219',
   '0.00000219',
   '0.00000219',
   '19.8044',
   '0.000043371636']],
 'XLM-BTC',
 [['1619317500',
   '0.00000863',
   '0.00000861',
   '0.00000863',
   '0.00000861',
   '653.5693',
   '0.005629652673']]]
```

I then try to convert it into a dataframe;

```py
import pandas as py
df = py.DataFrame(klines_list)
```

And this is the result;

```py
0
0   REQ-ETH
1   [[1619317500, 0.0000491, 0.0000491, 0.0000491,...
2   REQ-BTC
3   [[1619317500, 0.00000219, 0.00000219, 0.000002...
4   XLM-BTC
5   [[1619317500, 0.00000863, 0.00000861, 0.000008..
```

The structure of the DF is incorrect and it seems to be due to the way I have put my list together.

### I would like the quantitative data in a column corresponding to the correct entry in list a, not in rows. Also, the ticker data, or list a, ("REQ-ETH/REQ-BTC") etc should be in a separate column. What would be a good way to go about restructuring this?

Edit: @Ynjxsjmh
This is the output when following the suggestion below for appending a dictionary within the for loop

```py
REQ-ETH REQ-BTC XLM-BTC
0   [1619317500, 0.0000491, 0.0000491, 0.0000491, ...   NaN NaN
1   NaN [1619317500, 0.00000219, 0.00000219, 0.0000021...   NaN
2   NaN NaN [1619317500, 0.00000863, 0.00000861, 0.0000086...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) can accept a dict. It will construct the dict key as column header, dict value as column values.

```py
import pandas as pd

a = ["REQ-ETH","REQ-BTC","XLM-BTC"]

klines_data = {}

for i in a:
    klines = client.get_kline_data(i, '5min', 1619317366, 1619317606)
    klines_data[i] = klines[0]
    #                   ^
    #                   |
    #                   Add a key to klines_data

df = pd.DataFrame(klines_data)
```

```
print(df)

         REQ-ETH         REQ-BTC         XLM-BTC
0     1619317500      1619317500      1619317500
1      0.0000491      0.00000219      0.00000863
2      0.0000491      0.00000219      0.00000861
3      0.0000491      0.00000219      0.00000863
4      0.0000491      0.00000219      0.00000861
5         5.1147         19.8044        653.5693
6  0.00025113177  0.000043371636  0.005629652673
```

If the length of `klines` is not equal, you can use

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(klines_data, orient='index').T
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion of appending a dictionary. When trying your below code, I am getting a syntax error on the * symbol: Vklines_data.append({i: *klines})

Comment: perfect solution @Ynjxsjmh- this is now working exactly as intended. much appreciated for your help - thanks!